# Find ID in string of IDs separated with comma

Tags: mysql, regex

I would appreciate help with one regex.

I have a string of ids example `"123,55,68,890,456,333,168"`

How should the regex look like to find a specific id -- example **68**? Bear in mind that 168 shouldn't be returned.
There are four cases where the id could be positioned:

1. x (only one id in the list/string)
2. ,x, (somewhere in the middle of the string)
3. x, (at the beginning of the string)
4. ,x (at the end of the string)

I would use this regex as part of the SQL query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

`/(?:^|,)number(?:$|,)/` should do the trick.

`(?:)` is a *non-capturing group.* It looks for the value in the parentheses after the `:`, but doesn't include it in your result.

So this regular expressions says "Find `number` that is at the beginning or preceded by a comma, and at the end or followed by a comma."